# El significado de "si no estaréis"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Una conocida comentó lo siguiente:

> En esa ciudad necesitaréis coche sí o sí. Si no estaréis, mega limitados"

¿Qué significa "si no estaréis" en este contexto? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La coma no está en el lugar adecuado en la segunda frase, como me apunta @fedorqui.

> Si no, estaréis megalimitados

Es una frase condicional que se corresponde con una sencilla construcción if-else del inglés, lo que pasa es que se ha omitido parte de la frase.

> Si no tenéis coche, estaréis megalimitados.

Quizás reordenando un poco los elementos originales se entienda mejor la frase.

> Estaréis megalimitados en esa ciudad si no lleváis un coche.

En inglés la frase original sería algo así

> You definitely need a car in that city or else you're going to be very restricted

Comment: buena respuesta. Yo de incluso escribiría coma después del _si no_: _Si no, estaréis megalimitados_.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' no lo tenía claro. He dudado ahí. Actualizo. Gracias!

Comment: no hace falta que me referencies jeje :) Veo de hecho que el DPD lo menciona en su artículo [coma](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma): _1.2.12. se pone coma detrás de los elementos encabezados por locuciones preposicionales o adverbiales de valor condicional, concesivo, final, causal, etc._ Aunque no sé si aplica directamente, pues [si no](https://dle.rae.es/si) es locución conjuntiva.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Comment: @Maurice Nada, hombre, esta era fácil. :-)